# PHP database class, echos twice

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have just created a PHP class and i'm still getting my head around classes and how they work. How come my "Successfully Connected!" gets echo'ed twice? I have tried looking through it and can't get my head around why it would print twice.

```
            <?php


            include 'dbConfig.php';

            class dbConnect extends dbConfig
            {
                public $connectionString;
                public $dataSet;
                private $sqlQuery;

                    protected $host;
                    protected $userName;
                    protected $passWord;
                    protected $dbName;

                function dbParams(){
                    $this->connectionString = NULL;
                    $this->sqlQuery = NULL;
                    $this->dataSet = NULL;
                        // Creates an object that is created on the extend (dbConfig)
                        $dbParams = new dbConfig();

                        //Sets the variables in this class to match dbConfig's
                        $this->host = $dbParams->host;
                        $this->userName = $dbParams->userName;
                        $this->passWord = $dbParams->passWord;
                        $this->dbName = $dbParams->dbName;
                        // Object no longer needed, Null the object
                        $dbParams = NULL;
                }

                function dbConnect(){
                    $this ->connectionString = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->userName, $this->passWord, $this->dbName);

                    if($this->connectionString->connect_error){
                        echo "Connection failed";
                    } else{
                        echo "Successfully Connected!";
                    }

                    return $this->connectionString;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're running your constructor twice:

```
        class dbConnect extends dbConfig {
            function dbConnect(){
```

PHP supports using the class name as the constructor method's name, which dates back to the early days of PHP gaining object support, BEFORE they added the formal `__construct()` version as well.

So you automatically construct your object because of the above, then construct ANOTHER object with the following:

```
        $dbParams = new dbConfig();
```

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense, So when you don't define a __construct it will assing you one automatically?

Comment: @NathanK This is the PHP4 constructor methodology. You would name a function the same as the class name and it would become the constructor. It was kept in PHP 5 and is now [deprecated in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php). It is recommended you use only `__construct()` if you need a constructor

Comment: not really. if there's no __construct(), it simply won't run. but you have an implicit constructor by having your `dbConnect()` method. so that does run. If you DO have a __construct(), then the classname() version should get ignored.

Comment: Ahhhh! That's sorted now, Is it good practice to always make a __construct() even if you do not use it?

Comment: doesn't hurt to have an empty one, but also doesn't hurt to NOT have one. if you don't need to initialize anything at instantiation time, then not having one will save a few cpu cycles from not executing a do-nothing function.It would, however, prevent the ancestor's constructor from being inherited, however. if for some reason some other code does `$this->__construct()`, you'd end up running the ancestor constructor, and not the one for the current class.

Comment: I have now converted my dbConnect() to a __construct so when I $connection = new dbConnect(); it automatically connects. My issue right now is learning the correct ways of doing things and also learning at the same time :D

Comment: When I extend to dbConfig and include the dbConfig.php that means those variables are accessible by using $this->variablename right?

Comment: One last question before I leave you guys alone :D If I want to seperate my SQL functions into another file for example dbFunctions.php how would I do this using the dbConnect.php to ensure that its connected to the db.